# Why is a Complementary Filter a Good Approximation?

Tags: approximation, bayesian-network, kalman-filter

***Can someone help me understand what the full expression for the original complementary filter should be and why the one proposed by Colton is a good approximation?***

---

**Context:**
Having found some unofficial sources on Sensor Fusion ([Thousand Thoughts Sensor Fusion](http://www.thousand-thoughts.com/2012/03/android-sensor-fusion-tutorial/) and [The Balance Filter by Shane Colton](http://www.filedump.net/dumped/filter1285099462.pdf)) I'm struck by how the approximation of the complementary filter that is used there, i.e.

```
filtered_orientation = 0.98 * (filtered_orientation + delta_gyro_orientation*dt) + 0.02 * accelerometer_orientation
```

is accepted as a good approximation without any derivation or proof. I can't seem to figure out *why* it is a good approximation.

After having found definitions of the low-pass filter in Sedra and Smith's Microelectronic Circuits and W.T. Higgins 1975 paper A comparison of complementary and Kalman filtering (can be found on IEEE as well as via search engine as PDF), figure 1A in Higgins' paper seems to imply that the complementary filter is an addition of the high- and low-pass filtered data, like so

```
complementary = high-pass(x) + low-pass(y)
```

In case of sensor fusion this would yield:

```
complementary = high-pass(gyro) + low-pass(accel)
```

and thus

```
complementary = 0.98 * (old_gyro + delta_new_gyro*dt) + 0.98 * (old_accel) + 0.02 * (new_accel)
```

This seems wrong to me, I would expect a weighted adding of the two factors, instead of just adding them. So, I must have interpreted figure 1A wrong.